# Unable to save the QML object inside the Loader QML file

Tags: qt, qml

I try to save a variable from another QML object on root QML file using Settings. I can access the variable with `myloader.item.number` but when I try it on Settings it gives error: `Invalid alias target location: number` Is there a way to save the variable using Settings module?

MyPage.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
Rectangle {
    property alias number: combo.currentIndex
    color: "red"
    ComboBox{
        id: combo
        model: ["a","b","c"]
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import Qt.labs.settings 1.1
Window{
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("loader property is:", myloader.item.number)
    }
    //
    Loader{
        id:myloader
        //asynchronous: true
        active: true
        source: "MyPage.qml"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    /*
    // This can save the number with "property alias myNumber: mapage.number"
    MyPage{
        id: mapage
    }
    */
    Settings{
        id: settings
        // This gives error when using loader: Invalid alias target location: number
        property alias myNumber: myloader.item.number
    }
}
```

Comment: That probably won't work because the Loader's item is initially null. It becomes non-null after the source has loaded, but that's too late. An alias always needs an object to reference. See the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html).

Comment: I was afraid to hear this. My app has a Settings dialog. It has many controls so it makes the app slow. I wanted to use Loader to optimize the app. If it isn't possible I will have to use Local Storage.

Comment: You could just avoid using an alias, like this: `property int myNumber: myloader.item.number`

Comment: When I use int, it isn't saved. Current index is always 0.

Comment: What do you mean it isn't saved? You're not showing the code where you try to read from `myNumber`.

Comment: [This code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xc5pyXmvPq/) can save current index of the combo box, but [this code](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/npG7dmHvCj/) doesn't save the current index. The current index is always 0 even if I changed it to other index. Edit: I removed Loader in the first code, I forgot to remove component.onComplated.

Comment: First code edited here: paste.ubuntu.com/p/s4M34B5GnJ/

Comment: Ah, I'd never used the `Settings` object before. I just looked it up and now I understand how it works. You just need a different property to point the alias at. For instance, inside the `Loader`, add an int property, and then point the alias at that. You'll probably need to initialize the combobox to read from that int too. I'll try it out when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use an alias, you have to manually connect it to Settings. It worked when I did it like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import Qt.labs.settings 1.1
Window{
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("loader property is:", myloader.item.number)
    }
    //
    Loader{
        id:myloader
        active: true
        sourceComponent: myPage
        anchors.fill: parent

        Component
        {
            id: myPage

            MyPage
            {
                // Initialize the combobox from Settings
                number: settings.myNumber

                // Update the settings from the combobox
                onNumberChanged: settings.myNumber = number
            }
        }
    }
    Settings{
        id: settings
        property int myNumber
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@JarMan's answer is better solution. I have found another solution that I also used Settings object to MyPage.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import Qt.labs.settings 1.1
Rectangle {
    property alias number: settings2.comboIndex
    Settings{
        id: settings2
        property alias comboIndex: combo.currentIndex
    }
    color: "red"
    ComboBox{
        id: combo
        model: ["a","b","c"]
    }
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.10
import Qt.labs.settings 1.1

Window{
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 200
    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("loader property is:", settings.myNumber)
    }
    Loader{
        id:myloader
        source: "MyPage.qml"
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
    Settings{
        id: settings
        property int myNumber: myloader.item.number
    }
}
```

Settings of MyPage holds UI index for ComboBox, Settings of main.qml holds the value of ComboBox.